# How to prevent WMS caching on client side with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms, mapserver

I have created a WMS object like this:

```
var wms_Layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Plant Date", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {
    layers: 'test',
    datasource: 'WMS',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    visibility: true
});
```

and for drawing I tried both `wms_Layer.redraw();` & `wms_Layer.redraw(true);`

After launching the web browser I can retrieve the layer data, but the problem is the layer data is getting cached by default, which means until a new layer date comes from server the client hold the older data, 
is there a way to prevent the caching?

Comment: You may consider this post on stackexchange http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23769/prevent-openlayers-wms-layer-cache-by-browser

Comment: no the above link doesn't help